# Make predictions of an image directory - Conv Nets with tf.estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I made the training of a convolutional neuronal network, now I want to make predictions of a directory of images, for example I have 2 images in my folder I want to obtain the predictions for those 2 images, but when entering the directory in my code I only get the prediction for one of them, this is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import (
    saved_model_export_utils)
from tensorflow.contrib.training.python.training import hparam


pred_path="/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Sexta_Version_Combinacion/Direct/*.jpg"

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)#Comando para impresion de datos en la ejecucion

batch_size_pred=1

sess=tf.Session()#Creacion de session

#Modelo convolucional...........................................................................................
def cnn_model(features,labels,mode):

  input_layer=tf.reshape(features["x"],[-1,224,224,3])

  conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=30,
    kernel_size=[10,10],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    name="Convolucion_1")

  pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[4,4],strides=4,name="Pool_1")

  conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool1,
    filters=60,
    kernel_size=[5,5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    name="Convolucion_2")

  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[4, 4], strides=4,name="Pool_2")

  conv3=tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool2,
    filters=90,
    kernel_size=[5,5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    name="Convolucion_3")

  pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2,name="Pool_3")
  pool3_flat=tf.reshape(pool3,[-1,7*7*90],name="Flat_Pool")

  dense=tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool3_flat,units=2000,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_1")
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.5, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  logits=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout,units=2,name="Capa_final")

  predictions = {"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)}


  if mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,predictions=predictions)


def read_file(filename_queue):

  # Make a queue of file names including all the JPEG images files in the relative
  # image directory.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
  tf.train.match_filenames_once("/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Sexta_Version_Combinacion/Direct/*.jpg"))

  # Read an entire image file which is required since they're JPEGs, if the images
  # are too large they could be split in advance to smaller files or use the Fixed
  # reader to split up the file.
  image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

  # Read a whole file from the queue, the first returned value in the tuple is the
  # filename which we are ignoring.
  _, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

  # Decode the image as a JPEG file, this will turn it into a Tensor which we can
  # then use in training.
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)

  image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])
  image.set_shape((224, 224, 3))
  print(image)

  batch_size = 1
  num_preprocess_threads = 1
  min_queue_examples = 1
  images = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image],batch_size=batch_size,num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,capacity=min_queue_examples+3*batch_size,min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

  return images


def main(hparams):

  img_pred=read_file(pred_path)

  detector=tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,model_dir='/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Modelo_QuintaVersion')

  init_op=tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(init_op)

  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)


  img_p=sess.run(img_pred)

  pred_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x":img_p},
    shuffle=False)
  pred_results=detector.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
  print(next(pred_results))

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

For example in the placed directory I have 2 images but I get only the prediction of one of them, this is my result:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Modelo_QuintaVersion/model.ckpt-9000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
{'classes': 1}
```

How do I get the predictions for my two images? Thank you

**EDIT**
So my code would be like this?

```
def main(hparams):



  detector=tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,model_dir='/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Modelo_QuintaVersion')

  init_op=tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(init_op)

  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)


  pred_results=detector.predict(input_fn=lambda: read_file(pred_path))


  results = []
  for prediction in pred_results:
    results.append(prediction)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only requesting *one* prediction.
The `predict` of the `tf.Estimator` works like a generator, i.e. it yields single predictions based on the input function. When you do something like this

```
print(next(pred_results))
```

you are only requesting the *first* item of the generator. To obtain all predictions you should do something like:

```
results = []
for prediction in gun_detector.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
    results.append(prediction)
```

**Edit**: I have just noticed that you are making another mistake, too. At first, you get *one* batch of data and saving it in `img_p` by calling

```
img_p=sess.run(img_pred)
```

then you create a new input function which can only supply this one batch

```
pred_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x":img_p},
    shuffle=False
)
```

and let the estimator predict on this data

```
pred_results=detector.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
```

This does not make sense. Just replace these lines with

```
pred_results = detector.predict(input_fn=lambda: read_file(pred_path))
```

and everything should be working fine.

Comment: with your suggestion I obtain this : [{'classes': 1}]  I do not get the 2 predictions

Comment: @Darome Just remove the last three lines of your code, and use `pred_results`

Comment: but now how I print my results?